# How to install ElasticSeach plugins using docker compose

Tags: elasticsearch, docker, docker-compose, elasticsearch-plugin

I have a docker-compose.yml file with an elastic search image:

```
elasticsearch:
  image: elasticsearch
  ports:
    - "9200:9200"
  container_name: custom_elasticsearch_1
```

If I want to install additional plugins like the HQ interface or the attachment-mapper I have to do a manual installation with the following commands:

```
$ docker exec custom_elasticsearch_1 plugin install royrusso/elasticsearch-HQ
$ docker exec custom_elasticsearch_1 plugin install mapper-attachments
```

Is there a way to install them automatically when I run the `docker-compose up` command?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[Here](https://www.elastic.co/blog/elasticsearch-docker-plugin-management) is a blog post by Elastic pertaining to exactly that! You need to use a [Dockerfile](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/) which executes commands to extend an image. Your Dockerfile will look something like this:

```
FROM custom_elasticsearch_1

RUN elasticsearch-plugin install royrusso/elasticsearch-HQ
```

Comment: Mmm so there is no way to achieve that without adding another Dockerfile? I would like to do it inside the docker-compose

Comment: Docker compose uses the Dockerfile if you add the build command to docker-compose.yml. [Here](https://blog.codeship.com/orchestrate-containers-for-development-with-docker-compose/) is an example of use of a Dockerfile with Compose. But, [here](https://coderwall.com/p/ouemxq/install-plugins-on-elasticsearch-with-docker-compose) is an example of someone installing plugins without a Dockerfile.

Comment: I see, apparently an additional file is always required.

Comment: Thanks, @fylie. Your answer probably saved me hours today.

Comment: You're welcome @missingfaktor! Glad my answer helped :)

Comment: Thanks @fylie, I ended using the [second link](https://coderwall.com/p/ouemxq/install-plugins-on-elasticsearch-with-docker-compose) in your comment

Comment: this does not work with latest Docker version as of 2021. The `RUN plugin install <plugin_name>` throws error saying `plugin` in not found! 

The following works: `RUN elasticsearch-plugin install analysis-icu`

Please update the answer as this has been accepted as answer by the question owner.

Comment: @Asrar, done. (The command has nothing to do with Docker, it's changed by Elasticsearch.)

Answer (score 16):

Inspired by @NickPridorozhko's answer, but updated and tested with elasticsearch^7.0.0 (with docker stack / swarm), example with analysis-icu:

```
elasticsearch:
  image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.3.0
  user: elasticsearch
  command: >
    /bin/sh -c "./bin/elasticsearch-plugin list | grep -q analysis-icu 
    || ./bin/elasticsearch-plugin install analysis-icu; 
    /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh"
  ...
```

The main difference are the updated commands for ^7.0.0, and the use of the docker entrypoint instead of ./bin/elasticsearch (in a stack's context, you'd get an error related to a limit of spawnable processes).

Comment: this gives me an error "WARNING: plugin requires additional permissions " when i use it to install repoistory-s3

Comment: @Kay That doesn't seem to be related. See [this github issue](https://github.com/elastic/cloud-on-k8s/issues/2220) and this [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57406534/ingest-attachment-needs-more-rights).

Comment: For Opensearch, this works as well, with `/usr/share/opensearch/bin/opensearch-plugin` and `/usr/share/opensearch/opensearch-docker-entrypoint.sh`

Answer (score 7):

This works for me. Install plugin before and then continue with starting the elasticsearch.

```
elasticsearch:
  image: elasticsearch
  command:
    - sh
    - -c
    - "plugin list | grep -q plugin_name || plugin install plugin_name;
       /docker-entrypoint.sh elasticsearch"
```

Answer (score 7):

The ingest-attachment plugin requires additional permissions and prompts the user during the installation. I used the `yes` command :

```
elasticsearch:
  image: elasticsearch:6.8.12
  command: >
    /bin/sh -c "./bin/elasticsearch-plugin list | grep -q ingest-attachment 
    || yes | ./bin/elasticsearch-plugin install --silent ingest-attachment; 
    /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh eswrapper"
```

Comment: tried on docker compose can confirm this works

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Worked great for me on ES 7.x and does not require messing around with a custom `Dockerfile`.

Comment: Should we create a new docker image of Elasticsearch with this we are trying to add the azure repository plugin

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the `ELK` stack from `sebp/elk`

You need to setup your `Dockerfile` like

```
FROM sebp/elk

ENV ES_HOME /opt/elasticsearch
WORKDIR ${ES_HOME}

RUN yes | CONF_DIR=/etc/elasticsearch gosu elasticsearch bin/elasticsearch-plugin \
    install -b mapper-attachments
```

As seen on https://elk-docker.readthedocs.io/#installing-elasticsearch-plugins.

It should also work just for Elastic Search only as well.

Answer (score 0):

An example with Elasticsearch v6.8.15.
For simplicity we will use a `docker-compose.yml` and a `Dockerfile`.

The content of `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:6.8.15

RUN elasticsearch-plugin install analysis-icu
RUN elasticsearch-plugin install analysis-phonetic
```

And the content `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '2.2'
services:
  elasticsearch:
    #image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:6.8.15
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: elasticsearch
    environment:
      - cluster.name=docker-cluster
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - http.cors.enabled=true
      - http.cors.allow-origin=*
      - http.cors.allow-headers=X-Requested-With,Content-Type,Content-Length,Authorization
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    volumes:
      - esdata1:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
      - esplugins1:/usr/share/elasticsearch/plugins
    ports:
      - 9268:9200
    networks:
      - esnet
  elasticsearch2:
    #image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:6.8.15\
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: elasticsearch2
    environment:
      - cluster.name=docker-cluster
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - http.cors.enabled=true
      - http.cors.allow-origin=*
      - http.cors.allow-headers=X-Requested-With,Content-Type,Content-Length,Authorization
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
      - "discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts=elasticsearch"
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    volumes:
      - esdata2:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
      - esplugins2:/usr/share/elasticsearch/plugins
    networks:
      - esnet

volumes:
  esdata1:
    driver: local
  esdata2:
    driver: local
  esplugins1:
    driver: local
  esplugins2:
    driver: local

networks:
  esnet:
```

This is the default Elasticsearch 6.8.15 `docker-compose.yml` file from Elasticsearch website itself https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.8/docker.html#docker-cli-run-prod-mode. And I added two `named data volumes`, `esplugins1` and `esplugins2`, for two of these nodes. So these plugins can be persisted between `docker-compose down`.

Note, if you ever run `docker-compose down -v` then these volumes will be removed!

I commented out the `image` line and moved that image to `Dockerfile`. And then using `RUN` command added the `elasticsearch-plugin` install command. This `elasticsearch-plugin` command is natively available in the elasticsearch container. And you can check this once you are in the container shell.

Answer (score 0):

Just for somebody who is using elasticsearch version starting from `7` and want to install plugin through the dockerfile then use the `--batch` flag

```
FROM elasticsearch:7.16.2
RUN bin/elasticsearch-plugin install repository-azure --batch
```