# ingest-attachment needs more rights

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I have an app which uses the elastic search when I do apt ugrade I get

```
# Configuring Elasticsearch...
-> removing [ingest-attachment]...
-> Downloading ingest-attachment from elastic
[=================================================] 100%  
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@     WARNING: plugin requires additional permissions     @
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
* java.lang.RuntimePermission accessClassInPackage.sun.java2d.cmm.kcms
* java.lang.RuntimePermission accessDeclaredMembers
* java.lang.RuntimePermission getClassLoader
* java.lang.reflect.ReflectPermission suppressAccessChecks
* java.security.SecurityPermission createAccessControlContext
* java.security.SecurityPermission insertProvider
* java.security.SecurityPermission putProviderProperty.BC
See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/permissions.html
for descriptions of what these permissions allow and the associated risks.
-> Installed ingest-attachment
```

I'm not familiar with java at all. Can you tell me what I'm supposed to do?

Comment: It is not a Java question, but an elasticsearch security configuration issue. I’m not familiar with the plugin you’re using.

Comment: well since elasticsearch is based on java... I have no idea how I can grant permissions to this plugin :(

Comment: Does https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elastic-stack-overview/current/security-privileges.htm help? What version of elastic are you using? Since version 7.1 the Xpack is included, that enables permissions if I’m correctly informed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the discussion on elastic.io this is just a warning and by pressing "y" or using the option "-b", the required permissions are granted.

[Elastic 7.5 S3 plugin install warning message](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/elastic-7-5-s3-plugin-install-warning-message/211875)

> This is just a warning to inform you that the plugin requires additional permissions than those required by the core Elasticsearch process. If you hit y, those permissions will be automatically granted. See: Installing plugins with custom [docker image warning message](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/installing-plugins-with-custom-docker-image-warning-message/113490)

> As Elasticsearch plugins have to be installed on each node, we have [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/cloud-on-k8s/current/k8s-init-containers-plugin-downloads.html) on how to easily achieve that with ECK as well.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the -b flag while installing the plugin.
Then restart the elastic search. It should fix the issue.

Comment: I am building docker container for elastic 7.9.2. But, I am still getting these WARNINGs using the command with -b flag. `RUN bin/elasticsearch-plugin install -b ingest-attachment`